# Transform scale on :first-letter in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element, css-transforms

I am making drop-caps for the first letter of a paragraph using `transform: scale` on the pseudo element `:first-letter`. It works great in Chrome but not in Firefox, although `transform: scale` and `:first-letter` both work in Firefox for themselves.

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p:first-letter {
float: left;
margin-left: -36px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 53px;
transform: scale(1,2);
-ms-transform: scale(1,2);
-webkit-transform: scale(1,2);
-moz-transform: scale(1,2);
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjuq5/1/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter says, _“Only a small subset of all CSS properties can be used inside a declaration block of a CSS ruleset containing a selector using the ::first-letter pseudo-element”_, and `transform` is not in the list that follows. And this in accordance with http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#application-in-css AFAICS.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, attempting to transform the `:first-line` and `:first-letter` pseudo-elements was *crashing* Firefox, so [it was disabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=466845#c6). That was a long time ago, however; it may be worth revisiting in a new bug report.

There does not appear to be a pure CSS workaround, but you might be able to get away with using JavaScript to transplant the first letter into a child element and transforming that child element, instead of using `:first-letter`:

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var text = p.innerHTML;
p.innerHTML = '<span>' + text.charAt(0) + '</span>' + text.substring(1);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/cZLg9)

Comment: With JavaScript I can just about do anything. I am looking for pure CSS without JavaScript or changing markup, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Esser: Well there isn't one, so too bad.